# Text To Column Function

Tags: python, function, pandas, numpy

I am trying to write my own function in Python 3.5, but not having much luck.

I have a data frame that is 17 columns, 1,200 rows (tiny)

One of the columns is called "placement". Within this column, I have text contained in each row. The naming convention is as follows:

**Campaign_Publisher_Site_AdType_AdSize_Device_Audience_Tactic_**

The following code works perfectly and does exactly what i need it to do; I just don't want to do this for every data set i have:

```
    df_detailed = df['Placement'].str[0:-1].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(str)
    df_detailed = df.join(df_detailed)
    new_columns = *["Then i rename the columns labelled 0,1,2 etc"]*
    df_detailed.columns = new_columns
    df_detailed.head()
```

What I'm trying to do is build a function, that takes any columns with _ as the delimitator and splits it across new columns.

I have tried the following (but unfortunately defining my own functions is something I'm horrible at.

```
def text_to_column(df):
     df_detailed = df['Placement'].str[0:-1].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(str)
     headings = df_detailed.columns  
     headings.replace(" ", "_") 
     df_detailed = df.join(df_detailed)
     df_detailed.columns = headings  
     return (df)
```

and I get the following error "AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'replace'"

The end goal here is to write a function where I can pass the column name into the function, it separates the values contained within the column into new columns and then joins this back to my original Data Frame.

If I'm being ridiculous, please let me know. If someone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Hmmm, I am a bit confused - if `df_detailed` have columns `0,1,2,3..` then why is necessary replace headings with `.replace(" ", "_")`? Or something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `rename` function for replace columns names:

```
headings = df_detailed.columns  
headings.replace(" ", "_")
```

change to:

```
df_detailed = df_detailed.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(" ", "_"))
```

Or convert columns [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) because [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) does not work with `index` (`columns names`):

```
headings.replace(" ", "_")
```

change to:

```
headings = headings.to_series().replace(" ", "_")
```

Also:

```
df_detailed = df['Placement'].str[0:-1].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(str)
```

is possible change to:

```
df_detailed = df['Placement'].str.rstrip('_').str.split('_', expand=True).astype(str)
```

EDIT:

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'Placement': ['Campaign_Publisher_Site_AdType_AdSize_Device_Audience_Tactic_', 'a_b_c_d_f_g_h_i_']})
print (df)
                                           Placement  a
0  Campaign_Publisher_Site_AdType_AdSize_Device_A...  1
1                                   a_b_c_d_f_g_h_i_  2
```

---

```
#input is DataFrame and column name
def text_to_column(df, col):
    df_detailed = df[col].str.rstrip('_').str.split('_', expand=True).astype(str)
    #replace columns names if necessary
    df_detailed.columns = df_detailed.columns.to_series().replace(" ", "_")
    #remove column and join new df
    df_detailed = df.drop(col, axis=1).join(df_detailed)
    return df_detailed

df = text_to_column(df, 'Placement')
print (df)
   a         0          1     2       3       4       5         6       7
0  1  Campaign  Publisher  Site  AdType  AdSize  Device  Audience  Tactic
1  2         a          b     c       d       f       g         h       i
```

Comment: Your answers work individually, although the lambda function returned an error for me. Essentially, I would like some help incorporating that into a user defined function. In the function I've defined, is there something I should be adding? Removing? Is there a better way I could be doing something like this? Disregard the headings for now (i can rename them because each client will have different requirements, but would like to automate writing this each time if possible. Really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: Yes, then is possible use alternative solution `headings = headings.to_series().replace(" ", "_") ` ?

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Comment: Btw, I try improve solution - add parameter `df` - I think it is safer.